# lua: testscript.lua:37: '}' expected near '='

Tags: arrays, lua, lua-table

I'm trying to replace the following lua logic:

```
myarray = {}
myarray.value = {}
myarray.value["my-password"] = {}
    myarray.value["my-password"].value = "12345"
    myarray.value.user.value = "11111"
```

with:

```
myarray  = {value = {user= {value="11111}, "my-password"= {value = "12345"}}}
```

But I keep getting the above error message. Line 37 is the line where I'm consolidating the array initialization into one line.

I can't see where the bug is. 
Thanks

Comment: Please put answer in a separate answer rather than as part of your question. Moreover, the answer you have accepted is the one that worked/was most helpful so you don't need to restate in a separate answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When creating a new index for lua-table; you need to provide them in a square boxes:

```
myarray = {
    value = {
        ["my-password"] = {
            value = "12345"
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks.  The square brackets were the issue.

Comment: You only need the square brackets when the key is not an identifier.

Answer (score 3):

You missed the brackets:

```
myarray = {value = {["my-password"] = {value = "12345"}}}
--                  ^            ^
```

`foo.bar` is the syntactic sugar of `foo["bar"]`, the brackets can't be omitted in the latter form.

Comment: Yu, thanks!  hjpotter92's answer tipped me off. But I appreciate your help.